# P(a < X < b) < 1 for any a,b ∈ R with a < b.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am having the following question in an assignment:

"Let X be a random variable. Assume that the cumulative distribution function FX is continuous and strictly increasing on R.

Show that P(a < X < b) < 1 for any a,b ∈ R with a < b"

I am confused because I know that if X is continuous the following holds:
P(a < X < b)= P(a ≤ X < b)= P(a < X ≤ B)= P(a ≤ X ≤ b). I am helpful for tips on how to think about this and solve it.

Comment: Suppose there were some $a$ and $b$, $a<b,$ such that $P(a<X<b)=1$. Then $F(x)=1$ for all $x>b,$ so it isn't strictly increasing.

Answer (score 0):

The approach given in the comment by @RideTheWavelet works. That is to prove  this by contradiction. If the probability between $a$ and $b$ is  *equal*  to 1, then the cumulative distribution function will be flat (height = 1) from that point $b$ onwards, contradicting/violating the condition that it is strictly increasing.

Let's take this question to understand behaviors of cumulative distribution functions (CDF's) in a bit more generality.

For a discrete random variable (which takes on point masses on finite or countably infinite points), the CDF has to have jump discontinuities. Further, in that case, the CDF cannot be strictly increasing.

For a continuous random variable, the CDF strictly increasing implies a few things. First, from the gist of the present question, a strictly increasing CDF must have 1 as a horizontal asymptote (as $x \rightarrow \infty $ CDF $\rightarrow 1$). Similarly as  $x \rightarrow -\infty $ CDF $\rightarrow 0$. For the corresponding probability density function (PDF), it means that it has to be strictly above the $x$-axis. That is, if the CDF is strictly increasing, the corresponding PDF must have $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$.